# Can there be ugliness in the world of a Mathematical God?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mathematics, determinism, universe

Let us assume that Mathematics is infinite, represents the multiverse and beyond, and is the deterministic cause of everything we know to exist (the Big Bang and our universe, the formation of the planet earth, evolution, ourselves).  In other words, we live in a wholly mathematical universe.

Given those assumptions, we might identify Mathematics as a kind of "Mathematics God" --a being having many of the characteristics we associate with God (such as being the ultimate cause or foundation of everything that exists).

Under such a conception, is there any explanation as to why this "Mathematics God" would "choose" (this word is not meant to imply a conscious choice by a personified being) that there would be unfairness, cruelty, anomaly, immorality and ugliness (as readily noticed by everyone) instead of only beauty, symmetry, good-will and benevolence?

Comment: Is there any chance you could include a question mark here? I do note the third graph is conditionally framed as a question -- but it might help to make it a bit more explicit, and possibly explore a little further why this problem has become interesting or important to you in terms of your study of philosophy

Comment: There are a couple other problems with this question: Why would you call "the entire essence of Mathematics" the "Mathematics God"? Why would you think that mathematics "chooses" anything? Otherwise, I'm certain the question of why God would allow for evil has been asked before on this site.

Comment: Given that this question was teetering on the edge of being closed, and that I actually think it's a very good question, I took the liberty of making some major edits that might hopefully keep it open.  Please feel free to revert or adapt any changes that lose your original meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here's one reason: Noise.  The mathematical God is unselective as regards the reality it creates, and generates vast, indefinitely extensible hierarchies that are filled with collections within collections, some of whom are enormously complex and specific and others of whom are simple, unitary or all-encompassing.

Although the mathematical God conceives of the universe in totality in ways we might view as beautiful, that's not the full story of each of the various (also infinite) objects within that totality, and the mathematical God doesn't filter its creation to only contain those elements that are simple and binary.  Arguably, that's what makes applied Maths so useful to us.

Comment: I like this answer a lot.  The way you describe the "mathematical God" definitely reminds me of the Mandelbrot Set I referenced in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that input, i was not thinking of that ! This imensely helped me, i appreciate.

Comment: Can you suggest any keyword or name for a related topic to that, or do you have any suggestion of any topic, book or resource where i can read more about that idea ? It really really got me interested.

Comment: @nerdy hmm.  It's difficult to get the full picture I think without going deep into the maths and mathematical logic that underlies current academic practice, but I think Set Theory opens up a useful framework for and some really interesting questions about mathematical reasoning and the infinity.  On the other hand, if you're just interested in it from a casual perspective, Douglas Hofstadter is a very eloquent writer on the limits of mathematical expression, and his "Gödel, Escher, Bach" is a fun read.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematics is a language we use to understand the workings of the universe, it is not God. The universe can be written in the language of mathematics, it explains how events in the universe seem to occur from our perspective. It does not explain what the universe *is*. You seem to be confusing what mathematics actually does or explains. Wolfgang Pauli has written on this extensively. He said

> ...a mathematical formula can never tell us what a thing is, but only how it behaves; it can only specify an object through its properties. And these are unlikely to coincide in toto with the properties of any single microscopic object of our everyday life.

And Arthur Eddington:

> For example, we may admire the triumph of patience of the mathematician in predicting so closely the positions of the moon, but aesthetically the lunar theory is atrocious; it is obvious that the moon and the mathematician use different methods of finding the lunar orbit...But now we realise that science has nothing to say as to the intrinsic nature of the atom. The physical atom is, like everything else in physics, a schedule of pointer readings...
>
> ...matter is something that Mr. X knows. Let us see how it goes: This is the potential that was derived from the interval that was measured by the scale that was made from the matter that Mr. X knows. Next question: What is Mr. X? Well it happens that physics is not at all anxious to pursue the question: What is Mr. X? It is not disposed to admit that its elaborate structure of a physical universe is "The House that Mr. X built."...matter, in some indirect way, comes within the purview of Mr. X's mind is not a fact of any utility for a theoretical scheme of physics. We cannot embody it in a differential equation. It is ignored, and the physical properties of matter and other entities are expressed in their linkages in the cycle. And you can see how by the ingenious device of the cycle physics secures for itself a self-contained domain for study with no loose ends projecting into the unknown. All other physical definitions have the same kind of interlocking. Electrical force is defined as something which causes motion of an electric charge; an electric charge is something that exerts something that produces motion of something that exerts something that produces...ad infinitum.

Both quotes are from Quantum Physics and Ultimate Reality: Mystical Writings of Great Physicists by Michael Green.

Comment: I have the possibility that Mathematics is merely an invention ( "a language we humans invented in interaction with the physical world" ) but this leaves many problems, mainly the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic [problem of evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil) --it's just confusing people because you've introduced a nonstandard conceptualization of God.  Laying aside the mathematical aspects, you're really asking about "God of the Philosophers", the unity of all perfections, considered abstractly.  How can a perfect being contain or countenance any imperfection?

One answer to this question that works particularly well for the "Mathematical God" is that some region of contrast is necessary for there to be any structure at all.  In Platonism, Good is the only reality, evil is just the backdrop, a region of minimal good, just as cold is a region of minimal heat.  If we take such a view, we see that a universe with no "evil" is a universe where all that exists is the unbroken singularity of the perfect being.

When I conceptualize God mathematically, I think of the [Mandelbrot Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), a purely mathematical object of infinite complexity and obvious beauty.  Both the beauty and the complexity are contained in the structured pattern of points that tend to orbit towards the center ("heaven"?) or towards the outer darkness ("hell"?).  Without the existence of a region outside the set, the set could have no structure.

Comment: I actually disagree with this - I think the problem is very specifically about the possibility of deviations from aesthetic purity given a platonistic conception of mathematical ontology, and is only superficially about ethics/God.  That said, perhaps further clarification from the questioner may be valuable.

Comment: @PaulRoss In any Platonic system, the Beautiful IS the Good.  Given that, I'm not convinced that what you're saying is different from what I said.

Comment: Beauty and Goodness , although the majority of people would agree are the same, is still a subjective matter, mainly because the "noise" aspect mentioned by Paul Ross ( think of the existence of people that equate Beauty with Evilness )

Comment: @nerdy I'm far from sure the "majority" of people equate Beauty and Goodness, but it's a key part of the Platonism that both Paul Ross and I perceive as underlying your question.  Speaking of which, you might want to check out Plato.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very problematic. You listed some (deeply flawed or vague) assumptions and just called it "Mathematics God".  Now, "God" carries certain associations which have nothing to do with your assumptions.  But then, you asked a question about those associations.

In short, you just pulled a verbal bait-and-switch rather than a legitimate argument.

Let's look at your premises without the confounding label of "God":

1. Mathematics is infinite
2. Mathematics represents the multi-verse and beyond
3. Mathematics is the cause of everything we know to exist
4. Mathematics represents a Deterministic view of the world

Now, none of these assumptions even suggests that we should end up with a universe with beauty or any other characteristic relevant to human concerns.  The pseudo-dilemma of your argument came purely from the unjustified label of "God" which dragged in irrelevant associations.

Also, each of your premises is a problem.  I'd immediately reject all of them or demand clarification.

1. What does it mean to say Mathematics is infinite?
2. The existence of a multi-verse (or beyond) has NOT been established; at best, it's been suggested.  Therefore, it's incoherent to say Mathematics represents it.  Even if it was established, I'd challenge your contention that Mathematics represents it.  Mathematics has successfully represented some of our observations, and even then, only within a certain range of precision.
3. Mathematics is NOT the cause of everything that we know to exist,
   it's just a way of describing things.
4. Mathematics does NOT describe a deterministic view of the world;
   just look at Quantum Mechanics, which is non-deterministic AND uses
   Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it belongs to a traditional dichotomy in philosophy; that between form (*morphe*) and substance (*ousia*).

When mathematics is posited as a description of the universe it is as *form*; and not *substance*.

Imagine, for example, you are Descarte and have just discovered that you are a thinking being in the void; and suppose I hand you a mathematical description of an electron - will you be able to conjure up an electron?